# How to use socialize(facebook) with laravel 5.1

Tags: facebook, laravel

I followed [this guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication)

`Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider` in my `config/app.php` is ok, and aliases should also be ok : `'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,`

Here is my code :

config/services.php

```
'facebook' => [    
        'client_id' => 'xxxx',
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxx',
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/auth/fb',
]
```

Route

```
Route::get('auth/fb', 'FBController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/fb/callback', 'FBController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Socialite;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
class FBController extends Controller`
{

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }


    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    }
}
```

but is error in

`FatalErrorException in FBController.php line 14:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Socialite' not found`

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Even i also waiting for same answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934494/how-to-login-using-github-facebook-gmail-and-twitter-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: is FatalErrorException in return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect(); <<

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the error message ?

Comment: Sorry  error it has been put up

Comment: this is weird! try  return \Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect(); and see.

Comment: wow!   add '\'  is  ok!    yazfield  thank you:)

Comment: @Bruce.have you successfully authenticated using socialite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace use `Socialite;` with `use Socialize;` and all instances where Socialite replace it with Socialize

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Socialize;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
class FBController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialize::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialize::driver('facebook')->user();

    }
}
```