# Is google+ api necessary for Laravel's Socialite OAuth ? And also how to limit permissions?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5, google-oauth

I am using Socialite in my Laravel 5.1 project.
Using Google OAuth with socialite requires compulsory Google+ api enabled 
Or else it throws 
`ClientException in Middleware.php line 69:Client error: 403`

Even after Disabling Google Api i get this screen
[image]

Don't Wish to ask for who's in their `CIRCLE`.
I just want fields returned by Socialite -
 `Id, Nickname, Name, email-id &  Avatar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions in the consent screen are controlled by what scope you send.  You are probably sending a [scope](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth) of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`.  Remove that and you request the permissions from the user, but you also wont be able to access there Google+ data.

Also you cant change what permissions a scope gives those are supplied by Google.   If all you want is the persons id, nickname, name, email address you can try the profile scope I think it gives you that information but you should check the documentation and test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks , digged into Socialite and got this  `$scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read',
    ];`

Comment: Actually I have never used Socialite, I just know the inner workings of the Google authentication servers this is true for all languages.  :)

Comment: @DaImTo.if you know answer can you post here for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934494/how-to-login-using-github-facebook-gmail-and-twitter-in-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 0):

`vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/GoogleProvider.php`

**Change** 
 `$scopes = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read', ];`

**To** 
`$scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', ];`