# Check if the user has a password in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two ways of registering into my website: email or facebook login.

On facebook login, the user doesn't get a password. Which I need to read in some cases to know if the user will have to type the password to change their email for example

I want to, when returning the user object in laravel, also return a property has_pass that would keep this value..
Instead of creating a new database field, I just thought of using a function in the user model to determine if the password is blank, like this:

```
public function hasPass(){
    if($this->password){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works OK, but I want the data to return with the user object, so I can just check $user->haspass property, instead of having to call the function hasPass() at every check. So, how can I do it and is this a good way to do it?

Comment: `public function hasPass(){
    if($this->password){
        return $this;
    }
    return null;
}` and then `$user = Auth::user()->hasPass();`  then `if($user !== null)`

Comment: @raphadko.i am also facing problem in socialite.how you authenticate facebook user.i mean laravel auth require email and password but in facebook we get only email .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [an accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for `has_password`:

```php
class User extends Eloquent
{
    protected $appends = ['has_password'];

    public function getHasPasswordAttribute()
    {
        return ! empty($this->attributes['password']);
    }
}
```

Adding it to the `$appends` property will automatically add `has_password` to the array when the model is serialized.

Comment: I don't understand `$appends`. Does it mean the accessor will be appended to the model's attributes?

Comment: Yes. It will be appended to the rest of the model attributes when the model is serialized.

Comment: Ok, that being said, if I don't use `$appends`, the accessor will be available *only* in the object or collection. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Without the `$appends`, you can still access `$user->has_password`.

Comment: @Joseph Silber. i am facing same problem.if you know answer.can you post it to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934494/how-to-login-using-github-facebook-gmail-and-twitter-in-laravel-5-1