# auth not working

Tags: php

i am working on laravel socialite to login using gmail.i can able to store user info and if gmail id and email already exist then it should redirect to dashboard.

```
    public function googleCallback()
    {
     $user = Socialite::with('google')->user();
    $email=$user->email;
    $user_id=$user->id;
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' =>$email,'password'=>$user_id]))

            {
            //return redirect('user/UserDashboard');
            //return Redirect::to('user/UserDashboard');
                echo "i am here";
                }
}
```

in the above code if i use echo then it will print .suppose if redirect to dashboard it wont work.i don't know why redirect wont work for socialite.Can anyone tell where i am doing wrong ?
thank you

**Update:**
suppose if i login to my site using gmail or fb or github then data will store in my db.if that person login second time then it should redirect to user dashboard. the above code will check if auth::attempt exist or not.suppose if i print any think in inside if() block it works.suppose if i add redirect to dashboard then login through gmail and all not working

Comment: Does `redirect->action('SomeController')` or `redirect->back()` or `redirect->route('some_route')` work?

Comment: Andrew.not working.i am using laravel 5.1

Comment: if i print  print_r(Auth::user()); this in inside if then it will display all data

Comment: It might not work because of namespacing. Try using \Redirect::route() for named routes

Comment: if i use that give error like Route [user/UserDashboard] not defined.i am using middleware in route

Comment: @tester could you please elaborate what you want to say?

Comment: OK got it. you want to check whether email ID already exists. Am I right?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: my problem it will not redirect to dashboard if i add redirect inside true block

Comment: if you see my code there it will print i am here.but if i add return redirect()->intended('user/UserDashboard'); it wont work

Answer (score 1):

I don't know till what extent my answer would be correct but it should go somewhat like this:

```
public function googleCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::with('google')->user();
    $email=$user->email;
    $user_id=$user->id;

    $user_db = \App\User::where('email', $user->email)->first();

    if (count($user_db) == 1) {
        echo "i am here";
    } else {
        // Your registration process
        // With Login process i.e. auth()->attempt(YOURDATA);
    }
}
```

This is the only way that I could have done this thing. If anything else I can help in, put it in the comment box.

Comment: Just as simple as `auth()->logout()`

Comment: but your above code not using auth right .its just simple query right.

Comment: auth()->logout() will logout only when we set auth attempt know.is it correct ?

Comment: Maybe as per your point of view you are right. But as soon as you do else block, you should attempt user to login. And that's it. Check the updated answer

Comment: ya.i saw . i will try.if working then i will infrom you.

Comment: Well if it's not working then try changing if block statement to `count($user_db) !== 0`

Answer (score 0):

use this to redirect

```
return redirect()->intended('user/UserDashboard');
```