# Integrating Laravel, Facebook and Angular with token-based-authentication

Tags: angularjs, laravel, facebook-php-sdk, access-token, facebook-access-token

**My use case:**

User is already logged in automatically server side using Facebook with laravel and Socialite.

I check if the user exists in the db and if not create it and log them into laravel.

Then I need to start an Angular app and make sure they are logged in with Laravel / Facebook.

After reading this [article](https://github.com/scotch-io/laravel-angular-token-authentication), it looks like this token based approach is what I should take.

In the tutorial you serve a login form with Angular, and then pass the email and password to an authenticate controller (Laravel), which returns a token (create by [JWT-Auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)).

Once the token is in Angular all is well, my problem is that I want to get the token directly into Angular without a login form since the user is already logged in as mention above.

I'm wondering if I could just output the token in markup somewhere and then pick it up from Angular or would that somehow be a security risk? I guess people will only be able to view source and see their own token?

If this is the wrong way to do this, then how should I do it? Do I need to authenticate with Facebook with Javascript, and then create a new laravel user with ajax?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @iKode.i am facing socialite problem.if you know can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934494/how-to-login-using-github-facebook-gmail-and-twitter-in-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you could take is to add something to your `.config` block that checks for the presence of a JWT in local storage and if there isn't one there, makes a request to the API to see if the user is logged in on the Laravel side. If the user is logged in, a JWT is returned which can be picked up and saved in local storage. Since the `.config` block is run when the Angular app loads, this will only happen once, which is probably what you're looking for.

Here's what that might look like. First the Laravel side:

```
// AuthenticateController.php

...
// Simulates a user being logged in on the Laravel side through something
// other than credentials sent from the front-end. Obviously you would use
// Socialite

public function authenticate()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser(1);
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
...
```

Then the Angular:

```
// app.js

...
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $auth) {
    if(!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {

        // No credentials provided because the user is already logged in on the server
        $auth.login().then(function() {
            $state.go('users');
        }
    }

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
...
```

This would just run when the Angular app loads, which will be after your user has logged in with Socialite. It's essentially just checking whether there is a user logged in on the back end and if so, the token is retrieved. It's a bit hacky and the interface isn't obvious, so it might not be the *best* solution.

You would need to arrange your `authenticate` controller on the Laravel side such that it returns the token if the user has logged in via socialite or require credentials if he/she hasn't (which is the traditional login).

You could also look at this approach to see if it works for you: https://github.com/barooney/jot-bot/tree/socialite

Let me know if that works out!

Comment: sweet, thanks  a lot for your advice, I'll look into these options and let you know what works!

Comment: I don't see how I can call $auth.getToken() from the config. I can't seem to load the service into the config, which seems to be a reality of Angular, from what I have found... I only have access to authProvider in the config... or do you mean to access it directly, like so - localStorage.getItem('satellizer_token') ?

Comment: My bad, that's true of `config`. What about in the `.run` block, but outside of `$stateChangeStart`?

Comment: sorry don't know what you mean by outside of $stateChangeStart? Tried this code and debugger1 is hit first, then debugger1, perhaps you mean something else though... .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
                debugger2
            });
            debugger1....... not sure what $stateChangeStart is, what outside it means and why it's important...

Comment: No worries! I'll put a demo together in a bit, hang tight :)

Comment: @cienki.i am facing socialite problem.if you know can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934494/how-to-login-using-github-facebook-gmail-and-twitter-in-laravel-5-1